# what the pattern here in the event loop?

Tags: windows, winapi

In the following code

```
  Draw();


    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
              msg = PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE);
              if (msg)
              {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
              }
          Draw();
    }
```

why draw was called inside and outside the event loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a typical *game loop*.  It constantly draw frames, the PeekMessage() call ensures Windows messages are dispatched as normal, typically mouse and keyboard input to make the game interactive.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's called to do an initial draw before it starts the message pump. If there are no messages, it will have drawn something.

Comment: It would call Draw regardless

Comment: I forgot `PeekMessage()` was non blocking. Your comment does assume the first message doens't block though :)